# Get value from nested class using reflection

Tags: c#-3.0

Here I am posting a bit of code which have problem in use of reflection .In button Click I use a messagebox to show my needs. How can I get Name Value without using property.i like to use reflection. [I am able to get it using property]. Here I am getting an error “Non-static method requires a target.”  Please help me to correct this code.thanks in advance

```
public class CustomProperty<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public CustomProperty(T val)
    {
        _value = val;
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get { return this._value; }
        set { this._value = value; }
    }
}

public class CustomPropertyAccess
{
    public CustomProperty<string> Name = new CustomProperty<string>("cfgf");
    public CustomProperty<int> Age = new CustomProperty<int>(0);
    public CustomPropertyAccess() { }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CustomPropertyAccess CPA = new CustomPropertyAccess();
  CPA.Name.Value = "lino";
  CPA.Age.Value = 25;


  MessageBox.Show(CPA.GetType().GetField("Name").FieldType.GetProperty("Value").GetValue(null , null).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the object (CPA) in the GetValue call instead of null:

```
MessageBox.Show(CPA.GetType().GetField("Name").FieldType.GetProperty("Value").GetValue(CPA ,null).ToString());
```

Or was it as the second parameter? Don't remember exactly, so you should have a look in the MSDN for the exact signature of Property.GetValue.